# I got an offer to work in a different country

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, contracts, relocation, visa

I am currently working in Mexico as a Web Developer Engineer. This morning, I received an offer to work as a QA Test Engineer in Georgia, USA.

To be honest, I'm not afraid to change my location and I don't mind work as a Test Engineer so I accepted a telephone interview to have more details.
I don't know much about working in the USA, but I know how tricky some companies in Mexico can be.

So, I'm having some doubts about what the recruiter said, and the reason is recruiters always say that the position they offer will be the best job in the world, but it may not be exactly that kind of job.

**- He's going to pay a salary in MXN (pesos), plus the equivalent of $3,000 USD per month for travel expenses**

I'll earn some more money. I don't know if $3,000 will be enough to pay rent, services, and food - but I know that what it's supposed I'm going to earn it's nothing there. To be honest, it is way less than travel expenses.

I am thinking of asking the recruiter about the following subjects:

**- Ask for more money**

This may be sounds greedy but, I searched the web and found out what a Test Engineer makes in the USA and it's a lot more compared to what I'll be earning. So, I feel I need to ask for more money.
 
**- VISA / Contract**

They said they will work to take care of my eligibility to work in the US and any details in terms of a work contract, but what happens if you quit a job in the USA? I don't know, maybe I'll be there for 1 year or so, and I get bored and I decide to quit. Does that affect my "title" as an engineer or anything? I mean, in the USA, does a typical job contract say things like "you can not work with other IT companies in N months / years" or something like that?

I do not know what else to ask, but thanks in advance if any of you has any advice about what I should ask the recruiter or any extra tip to help me.

Comment: Is that 3000 a month USD or Pesos?  The US government has standard rates for travel expenses that are used by the IRS.  For Georgia this is a  *minimum* of $USD90 per day for accommodation and $USD50 per day for food.  See https://www.gsa.gov/travel/plan-book/per-diem-rates/per-diem-rates-lookup/?action=perdiems_report&state=GA&fiscal_year=2018&zip=&city=

Comment: Is this a contract or a permanent position?  Will they be paying you in the US or in Mexico?  What class of Visa are they suggesting to apply for?

Comment: @PeterM Let me answer all questions. They said 3000 USD / month + my salary (around 1000 USD) and thats the tricky part.. It's like im gonna be working for a Mexican Company but my work place will be in Georgia, so they will be paying me while im in USA . 
The time for the contract is undefined and for for the Visa they only said it's supposed to be a kind of "Working visa" (dont an mentioned the exact name).

Comment: Is this correct: You will be based in the US, but your salary will be paid to you by the Mexican company to a Mexican bank account?

Comment: I am going to edit your post to make the currency for the travel expense a little more clear. In a comment you just said $3000 USD, which is about 20 times what 3000 pesos is worth. At first read, I thought you meant 3000 pesos (about $150 USD)

Comment: Would USD 1,000 per month salary even meet legal minimum wage requirements for a standard 40 hour week?

Comment: @Mawg If the OP is being employed/paid by a Mexican company then US wage laws are kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Not if he is working in the US, I think. But, maybe that's a question for https://law.stackexchange.com/ In any case, the salary is extremely low. Maybe they are trying to pay him part of it as expenses to avoid social security contributions or something else ...

Comment: Will you be exclusively in the US, or will you be traveling back and forth? If the latter, will you be receiving a flat rate of $3k/month, or will it be pro rated for the time you spend in the US?

Comment: @Mawg Suppose the OP telecommutes from Mexico to Georgia, but is paid in Mexico, does he is status suddenly change when he stops across the border?  As per SS, yes the US company is avoiding paying that by hiring the Mexican company.  But the Mexican company will be paying the Mexican equivalent of SS to the Mexican government.

Comment: @Acccumulation, it's supposed to i'll be working only un US. And the recluiter didnt said nothing about any increase for the time i'll be there.. just said "if you're doing well , you maybe have the oportunity to sign a direct contract with them. This can be in one year or maybe more "

And about the salary.. yes, it's low.. The working salary is waaay lower in Mexico than in US, even for an engineer. lol

Comment: "but what happens if you quit a job in the USA? "  -- as a TN visa worker, you have a limited amount of time to look for another job in the same IT industry or have to go back to Mexico. Have you asked if they can sponsor you to a H1B visa?

Comment: $3,000 for a single person a month in Georgia is more than enough for rent, food, internet, etc.

Comment: @PeterM if, for the sake of argument, based on nothing at all in the question, and belied by the OP's mentioning a visa, if he were to be working remotely from Mexico, then the fact that "living expenses" are three times salary (and ***extremely*** generous for Mexico) should ring warning bells. In fact, if he is working from home, "living expenses", no matter how much, should be a red flag.

Answer (score 4):

In thinking about it, these questions are probably better answered on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com but I'll answer here anyway.  Maybe someone will move the question across to that site.

**Salary/Travel Expenses**

The amount of travel expenses are on the low side for  US government recommendations for Georgia as per [FY 2018 Per Diem Rates for Georgia](https://www.gsa.gov/travel/plan-book/per-diem-rates/per-diem-rates-lookup/?action=perdiems_report&state=GA&fiscal_year=2018&zip=&city=).  However these rates are based on staying in a hotel and buying every meal at a restaurant. But if you are staying for an extended period in your work location, you should be able to obtain a lease on an apartment etc that will be cheaper than a hotel room - which also allows you to cook your own food for cheaper prices etc.  You need to look at hotel and apartment prices in the location that you will staying to see if these travel expenses make sense.

The salary of $USD1000 is very low for the US, but it may be more than what you would get in Mexico.  And this is the equation the recruiter is looking for - pay you more than Mexico (but way less than the US), but charge the client less than US rates and profit from the difference.  It is up to you to decide if this is acceptable - however I would try and push for more money.  But remember that the more they pay you the less profit the recruiter makes.

But as per the comment from bharal, you will also be gaining valuable experience.  In addition you should be making valuable contacts that could help you move-up to a better paying position (EG you might be able to get future employment without using this recruiter and hence make more money)

**Visa**

I am concerned that the recruiter has been vague about the class of visa you would require, because if you are a Mexican national you are potentially eligible for [Visas for Canadian and Mexican NAFTA Professional Workers](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/visas-canadian-mexican-nafta-professional-workers.html)

> The nonimmigrant NAFTA Professional (TN) visa allows citizens of
>   Canada and Mexico, as NAFTA professionals, to work in the United
>   States in prearranged business activities for U.S. or foreign
>   employers.

However you still need to fall under one one [of the defined categories](http://www.nafsa.org/_/file/_/amresource/8cfr2146.htm).  From the job description I think you might fall under:

> --Computer Systems Analyst--Baccalaureate or Licenciatura Degree; or Post-Secondary Diploma (3) or Post Secondary Certificate (4) and three
>   years' experience.
>
> (3) "Post Secondary Diploma" means a credential
>   issued, on completion of two or more years of post secondary
>   education, by an accredited academic institution in Canada or the
>   United States.
>
> (4) "Post Secondary Certificate" means a certificate
>   issued, on completion of two or more years of post secondary education
>   at an academic institution, by the federal government of Mexico or a
>   state government in Mexico, an academic institution recognized by the
>   federal government or a state government, or an academic institution
>   created by federal or state law.

Note that I am not qualified to give legal advice on Visas. But if the recruiter suggests that you work under an inappropriate visa then I would walk away from the offer as the penalties for visa fraud can be very strong.  EG Up to 10 years permanent ban from the USA.  I would suggest consulting a Visa specialist not connected to the recruiter in order to evaluate the eligibility of your application.

Note that part of the eligibility of this visa category is that you have:

> .. a contract or employment letter from your employer in the United
>   States confirming your upcoming employment..

This says to me that you can only work for the one company and that if you quit or your contract is terminated, that you have to return to Mexico (Note again I am not a Visa specialist).

**Non-compete**

You have said that you will be employed by a Mexican company, so to me that means any non-compete clause of a contract would be adjudicated under Mexican law.  So there would be no restrictions on working for other US companies - as long as you can get employment with them!  However, again I recommend you get legal advice from a professional in Mexico.

**Taxation**

You didn't ask this in your question, but taxation is an important issue and can have huge financial consequences if you get it wrong.  You may be eligible to pay US or GA taxes depending on where you are paid.  (Again I'm not a tax specialist .. blah blah blah).  However if you are solely paid in Mexico, to a Mexican bank account you may be able to side-step paying tax in the US.

And if you can structure it correctly you might even avoid paying some taxes in Mexico assuming there are *legal* loopholes.  EG In the US money paid as travel expenses is tax deductible up to the amount specified in the Per Diem tables.  So if I was paid $USD93 per day for accommodation and $USD51 for Meals and Incidentals, but I only spent a total of $72 per day on those items, I can still claim the full $144 per day as a deduction - thus effectively giving me $72 per day tax free.

Comment: Taxes are based on residence and work location, not where your bank account is. If the OP is being paid for work done in Georgia, then the IRS and Georgia are going to want taxes.

Comment: @Acccumulation Actually no depending on the Visa class.  I have previously worked in the US for an Australian company for an extended period on a L1/L2 visa and have been paid in Australia and taxed in Australia, not the US.

Comment: Did the IRS know about it?

Comment: @Acccumulation it was nothing to do with the IRS.  That's the whole point.

Comment: Omg, there are too many things that I have to consider ... now my answer is more inclined to a "_Thanks for the offer but no_". I do not want to have a bad time.
Thanks for everything!

Comment: @WiLLyxVKei Working internationally is harder, but it has some great benefits too.   But if you don't want to do this now I would still say to get these answers so you can better decide again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If they aren't offering a comparable wage to that of a QA tester in the region, don't take the offer. If they include a no-compete clause in your contract, also don't take the offer. If they won't handle visas for you, don't take the offer. Really, this seems like they are just trying to hire you to save money on hiring a local QA tester, and don't really appreciate your skill-set enough to pay you fairly.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that after searching for a while. 
It's like im going to be paid for this like a common job here where i live

Comment: might be good for the OP to get some US experience though, which would presumably increase their value in Mexico and/or lead to new, better paying work in the states?

Comment: That is objectively poor advice. The average QA tester in Georgia makes 6261 dollars a month, and he would be making 4000 dollars. That's 2/3rds the average, and it isn't an entry level position. He should be paid a reasonable amount of money for the job he is being asked to do, where he is being asked to do it. https://www.indeed.com/salaries/QA-Tester-Salaries,-Atlanta-GA